# How to create CCR, IAR, and ACC registers in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, cpu-registers

I am currently doing a project for my Java programming class and in it I need to create a code that simulates a simple computer.  One of the components of this is creating registers that simulate the ACC, IAR, and CCR.  I have asked my teacher for help and he has shown me examples of how to create a register although I am still not sure how to make registers that will simulate the ACC, IAR, and CCR. The way I'm supposed to do it is create the registers in a separate Java file that's in the same folder as my current one(shown below) and then use those registers in this current code to execute instructions. Please tell me if there's any way you all know how to do this. The Register and Register Test classes are the ones that are supposed to show me how to create a register(register class) and how to use it in my code (register test). Also by IAR, ACC, and CCR I mean Accumulator, Instruction Address Register, and Condition Code Register. I have placed the register code in the same folder as the first code so far but I'm not sure how to create registers that will simulate these 3.
Here is my code(I'm supposed to have the user choose an option and use the registers to execute the program and in the following method display it):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
  *   Imitates the operations of a simple computer.  
  *
  *   @author 
  *   @version 10/19/2021
  */

public class Interpreter_IST140
{
   /**
     *   Entry point for the class (program).
     *
     *   @param args The command-line arguments.
     */
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      // Create a Scanner object...
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     
      // Declare a boolean variable to hold the result of the input validation
      boolean menu_return2 = false;
     
      // Declare a variable for the user input
      int menuInput2 = 0;
     
      // Create a counter variable for the while loop...
      int i = 0;
     
      // Declare an int array to store instructions
      int [] instructions = new int [16];
     
      // Prompt the user whether they want to return to the main menu...
      while (i >= 0) {
         // Call input validation method...
         menu_return2 = userResponse(scnr);
         // The user wants to return to the main menu...
         if (menu_return2 == true) {
            // Call user menu choice method...
            menuInput2 = userMenuChoice(scnr);  
            // Execute the proper method depending on user choice...
            // Did the user choose option 1?
            if (menuInput2 == 1) {
               // User chose option 1, call method menuOp1...
               menuOp1 (scnr, instructions);
               // Increment the counter variable...
               i++;
            }
            // Did the user choose option 2?
            else if (menuInput2 == 2) {
               // User chose option 2, call method menuOp2...
               menuOp2 (scnr, instructions);
               // Increment the counter...
               i++;
            }
            // Did the user choose option 3?
            else if (menuInput2 == 3) {
               // User chose option 3, call method menuOp3...
               menuOp3 (instructions);
               // Increment the counter...
               i++;
            }
            // Did the user choose option 4?
            else if (menuInput2 == 4) {
               // User chose option 4, call method menuOp4...
               menuOp4();
               // Increment the counter...
               i++;
            }
            else if (menuInput2 == 5) {
               // User chose option 5, call method menuOp5...
               menuOp5();
               // Increment the counter...
               i++;
            }
            else if (menuInput2 == 6) {
               // User chose option 6, call method menuOp6...
               menuOp6();
               //Increment the counter...
               i++;
            }
           
         }
         // The user doesn't want to return to the main menu...
         else {
            // End the program...
            break;
         }
      }
     
   }
     
   /**
     *   Performs user input of whether to return to the main menu or not.
     *   Validates the input value and returns it to the calling method.
     *
     *   @param scnr The Scanner object for user input.
     *   @return Returns the validated user input.
     */

   public static boolean userResponse(Scanner scnr)
   {
      // Prompt the user
      System.out.print("Would you like to return to the main menu? (YES/NO) ");
    
      // Input the user's response
      String menuInput = scnr.next();
    
      // Declare a flag variable
      boolean is_valid_response = false;
     
      // Declare second boolean for whether to return to the main menu...
      boolean menu_return = false;
    
      // Determine whether wants to return to the main menu
      if (menuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
         // Yes! Set to true
         is_valid_response = true;
         // Set menu return to true
         menu_return = true;
      }
      else if (menuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
         // No! Set to false
         is_valid_response = true;
      }
      else {
         // ERROR! Not valid
         System.out.println("ERROR! Please enter either yes or no.");
      }
    
      // Return the results
      return menu_return;
     
   }
  
   /**
     *   Displays the user menu to the screen.
     *
     */
    
    public static void displayMenuOptions()
    {
       // Output the display menu, formatted appropriately...
      System.out.printf("\n%20s\n\n", "Main Menu");
     
      // Option 1
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "1. ENTER PROGRAM");
     
      // Option 2
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "2. EXECUTE PROGRAM");
     
      // Option 3
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "3. DISPLAY PROGRAM");
     
      // Option 4
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "4. EXPORT PROGRAM");
     
      // Option 5
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "5. IMPORT PROGRAM");
     
      // Option 6
      System.out.printf("%5s\n", "6. QUIT PROGRAM");
     
    }

   /**
     *   Performs user input of whether to return to the main menu or not.
     *   Validates the input value and returns it to the calling method.
     *
     *   @param scnr The Scanner object for user input.
     *   @return menuInput Returns the validated user menu choice.
     */
  
   public static int userMenuChoice(Scanner scnr)
   {
       // Call the display menu method
       displayMenuOptions();
      
       // Declare an integer for the user's menu choice
       int menuInput = 0;
      
       // Declare a flag variable to determine valid input
       boolean valid_menu_input = false;
      
       // Determine whether the user made a valid menu choice
       while (!valid_menu_input) {
          // Prompt them to enter their desired option
          System.out.printf("\n%5s", "ENTER THE OPTION THAT YOU DESIRE: ");
         
          // Input the user's menu choice
          menuInput = scnr.nextInt();
                
          // The user entered a valid option
          if ((menuInput >= 1) && (menuInput <= 6)) {
                         
             // The user entered valid input set to true
             valid_menu_input = true;
            
             // Echo-print their chosen option
             System.out.printf("\n%5s\n", "YOU HAVE CHOSEN OPTION: " +
             menuInput + ".");
            
          }
         
          // The user did not enter a valid option
          else {
             System.out.printf("\n%5s\n",
             "SORRY, YOU MUST CHOOSE AN OPTION BETWEEN 1-6.");
          }
         
       }
       //  Return the user's menu choice...
       return menuInput;
   }
   /**
     *   Enters the user's program instructions into the main memory
     *   in the form of three digit hexadecimal memory addresses.
     *
     *   @param scnr The scanner object for user input.
     *   @param instructions The int array for storing program instructions.
     *   @return j The number of inputs made by the user.
     */
    
   public static int menuOp1(Scanner scnr, int [] instructions)
   {
      // Declare a counter variable j...
      int j = 0;
     
      // Declare a string variable for the user instructions...
      String userInput = "abcd";
     
      // Print out the option title...
      System.out.println("\nENTER PROGRAM\n");
     
      // Input the user instructions...
      while (!userInput.equals("####")) {
         // Display the input line...
         System.out.print(String.format("%04X", j) + ": ");
        
         // Input the user's instructions...
         userInput = scnr.next();
         // End the loop if #### entered...
         if (userInput.equals("####")) {
            // Use a break to end the loop...
            break;
         }
         // Continue inputting instructions...
         else {
            // Input the user's instructions into the array...
            instructions [j] = Integer.parseInt(userInput, 16);
            // Increment the counter...
            j++;
         }
      }
     
      // Return the # of inputs j...
      return j;
   }
  
   /**
     *   Executes the program instructions using the three registers
     *   as well as user input.
     *
     *   @param scnr The scanner object for user input.
     *   @param instructions The int array for storing program instructions.
     *   @return optionOutput The final results of executing the program.
     */
  
   public static int menuOp2(Scanner scnr, int [] instructions)
   {
      // Declare an int variable for the final results
      int optionOutput = 0;
     
      // Print out the option title...
      System.out.println("\nEXECUTE PROGRAM\n");
     
      // Returns the results...
      return optionOutput;
   }
   /**
     *   Displays the program currently stored in the main
     *   memory to the screen.
     *
     *   @param instructions The int array for storing program instructions.
     */
  
   public static void menuOp3(int [] instructions)
   {
      // Print out the option title...
      System.out.println("\nDISPLAY PROGRAM\n");
     
      // Display the instructions in the memory...
      for (int i = 0; i < instructions.length;i++) {
         // Only display iterations that have instructions...
         if (instructions[i] != 0) {
            // Display the input line...
            System.out.print(String.format("%04X", i) + ": ");
            // Display the ith instruction...
            System.out.println(instructions[i]);
         }
      }
      // Print a blank line to the screen...
      System.out.print("\n");
   }
  
   /**
     *   Exports the current program as a text file (user-specified).
     *
     */
  
   public static void menuOp4()
   {
  
   }
  
   /**
     *   Imports a program from a user-specified file.
     *
     */
  
   public static void menuOp5()
   {
  
   }
  
   /**
     *   Ends the program.
     *
     */
  
   public static void menuOp6()
   {
      // Terminate the program...
      System.exit(0);
   }
}

/**
  *   Simulates a CPU register. Internally, the data is stored as a 
  *   16-bit integer.
  *   
  *   @author 
  *   @version 1.0, 1/01/2017
  */
  
public class Register
{
     /**
       *  Data property for the class; stores the actual register value.
       */
     private int m_register_value;


     /**
       *  Default constructor for the class. Initializes the 
       *  Register value to 0.
       */
     public Register()
     {
         // initialize the data...
         m_register_value = 0;
     }
          
     /**
       *  Sets the value of this Register object.
       *  @param new_value A Java int value.
       */ 
          
     public void setValue(int new_value) 
     {        
         // set the value...
         m_register_value = new_value;     
     } 
     
     /**
       *  Sets the value of this Register object.
       *  @param new_value A hexadecimal String value.
       *  @throws NumberFormatException if the String is not a base 16 number.
       */ 
          
     public void setValue(String new_value) throws NumberFormatException
     {          
         // set the value...
         m_register_value = Integer.parseInt(new_value, 16);     
     }     
     
     /**
       *  Returns the value of this Register object. 
       *  @return The int value of this Register 
       *          object.
       */ 
          
     public int getValue() 
     {
         // return the value...
         return m_register_value;
     }     
     
     /**
       *  Returns an exactly 4-digit hexadecimal representation of this 
       *  Register's value.
       *  @return A 4-digit hexadecimal representation of this 
       *          Register's value.
       */     
     public String getHexString()
     {        
         // returns the 4-digit hex representation....
         return String.format("%04X", m_register_value);
     }
}

/**
  *   Unit Test for the Register class.
  *   
  *   @author 
  *   @version 1.0, 10/27/2021
  */

public class RegisterTest
{
    /**
      *   Entry point for the class (program).
      *
      *   @param args The command-line arguments.
      */
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       // Create a Register object...
       Register r = new Register();

       // Set the register value (32 in base 10 is 20 in hex)...
       r.setValue(32);  
       // Output the contents of the register in hex (Base 16)...
       System.out.println( r.getHexString() );
       // Output the contents of the register in Base 10...
       System.out.println( r.getValue() );
       
       // Output a new line...
       System.out.println();
       
       // Set the register value (F021 in base 16 is 61473 in Base 10)...
       r.setValue("F021");  
       // Output the contents of the register in hex (Base 16)...
       System.out.println( r.getHexString() );
       // Output the contents of the register in Base 10...
       System.out.println( r.getValue() );         
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.printf("\n%20s\n\n", "Main Menu");   is a strange way to do System.out.println("\nMain Menu\n");

Comment: In your menuOp2 method you need to run code that will go through your instruction array and interpret the instructions and update the registers.  You haven't even begun to code that and it is the part you are asking about.  You haven't shown any code related to your registers (the code your instructor showed you).  Please show us that code as it is the part that matters here.

Comment: None of that user-interaction code really has much to do with the actual question, which is asking how to simulate machine registers. What have you tried?  You say it was suggested that you create a register class in a separate Java source file. Have you done that?

Comment: System.out.print(String.format("%04X", i) + ": ");  is a messy way to do System.out.printf("%04X: ", i);

Comment: By the way, your abbreviations are not universal standards.  I'm guessing ACC is accumulator, IAR is instruction address register, CCR is condition code register. Right?

Comment: @swpalmer thats just how my teacher wants us to output the menu

Comment: @user16632363 yeah those are the three registers im supposed to simulate my fault i didn't realize that wasn't universal.